# How to merge n number rows in dataframe with condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, hbase

I have a dataframe like below:

```
Rowkey timestamp col_1 col_2 col_3.... col_n
1234   165789    20    null  30   ...  null
1234   155789    20    20    null ...  40
1234   145789    20    10    30   ...  50
```

and except to transform it into following dataframe:

```
Rowkey timestamp col_1 col_2 col_3.... col_n
1234   165789    20    20    30   ...  40
```

I want latest timestamp. Also, if a cell is `null`, and following cell with same `Rowkey` has value, then that value should be used.

I am using Spark with Scala.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in Scala or Python? Please remove one of the tags `scala` or `pyspark`.

Comment: Dynamo data frame?

Comment: Now I edited please check

Comment: are you looking for a pyspark solution? if not, please remove the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take:

Use a Window function to select the first non-null value of each `Rowkey` partition, ordered by `timestamp` - then drop duplicates to have only one row per `Rowkey`.

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val simpleData: Seq[(String, Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)] = Seq(
  ("1234",165789,20,null,30, null),
  ("1234",155789,10,20,null, 40),
  ("1234",145789,2,10,30, 50),
  ("123e4",145789,2,10,30, 50)
)

val someDF = simpleData.toDF("Rowkey","timestamp","col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4")

someDF.show()


val listCols= List("Rowkey","timestamp","col_1","col_2","col_3","col_4")

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Rowkey").orderBy($"timestamp".desc).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

someDF.select(
  listCols.map(m=> first(m, true)
  .over(windowSpec).alias(m)
  ) :_*
)
.dropDuplicates()
.show()
```

Result:

```
+------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Rowkey|timestamp|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|
+------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1234|   165789|   20| null|   30| null|
|  1234|   155789|   10|   20| null|   40|
|  1234|   145789|    2|   10|   30|   50|
| 123e4|   145789|    2|   10|   30|   50|
+------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+

+------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Rowkey|timestamp|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|
+------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1234|   165789|   20|   20|   30|   40|
| 123e4|   145789|    2|   10|   30|   50|
+------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```